# How do I use the "Barton–Nackman trick" to implement trival methods?

Tags: c++, templates

Inspired of boost::operators I thought the Barton-Nackman idiom could be used to implement from trival member methods.

Following is what I have tried (does not compile)

```
template<typename T>
class impl_get_set {
    typename T::storage_type get() const {
        return static_cast<const T *>(this)->data_;
    }

    void set(typename T::storage_type d) {
        *static_cast<T *>(this)->data_ = d;
    }
};

struct A : public impl_get_set<A> {
    typedef int storage_type;
    storage_type data_;
};

struct B : public impl_get_set<B> {
    typedef double storage_type;
    storage_type data_;
};
```

As this does not compile there is clearly something I have got wrong. My question is, can this be done, and if so how?

Comment: That's CRTP, not the Barton-Nackman trick

Comment: -1 for no error message.

Comment: For what is worth, it appears that C++ already provides the functionality the example strives to provide. It's called a public member variable.

Comment: How about `struct A { int data; }; struct B { double data; };`?

Comment: Well, this is just a simple illustration of the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using CRTP, you have to take care when designing the base, i.e. `impl_get_set` in this case. When the derived class instantiates the base specialization, e.g. as done with `A: public impl_get_set<A>`, the `A` class is still incomplete.

However the definition of `impl_get_set` uses `typename T::storage_type` in a member function declaration. This use requires a complete `T`. The C++03 way to solve that is to make any associated type that the CRTP base may need part of the class template parameters:

```
template<typename Derived, typename StorageType>
struct get_set {
    typedef StorageType storage_type;

    // It's possible to define those inline as before where
    // Derived will be complete in the body -- which is why
    // CRTP is possible at all in the first place
    storage_type get() const;
    void set(storage_type s);

    // Convenience for clients:
protected:
    typedef get_set get_set_base;
};

struct A: get_set<A, int> {
    // Member type is inherited
    storage_type data;
};

template<typename T>
struct B: get_set<B<T>, double> {
    // Incorrect, storage_type is dependent
    // storage_type data;

    // First possibility, storage_type is
    // still inherited although dependent
    // typename B::storage_type data;

    // Second possibility, convenient if
    // storage_type is used multiple times
    using typename B::get_set_base::storage_type;
    storage_type data;
    void foo(storage_type s);
};
```

[`boost::iterator_facade`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#reference) is a good example of a well-written C++03-style CRTP wrapper from Boost.Iterator.

---

C++11 gives another way to write a CRTP base thanks in part to default template arguments for function templates. By making the derived class parameter dependent again, we can use it as if it were complete -- it will only be examined when the member function template of the CRTP base specialization is instantiated, once it is complete, and not when the CRTP base specialization itself is:

```
// Identity metafunction that accepts any dummy additional
// parameters
template<typename T, typename... Dependent>
struct depend_on { using type = T; };

// DependOn<T, D> is the same as using T directly, except that
// it possibly is dependent on D
template<typename t, typename... D>
using DependOn = typename depend_on<T, D...>::type;

template<typename Derived>
struct get_set {
    template<
        // Dummy parameter to force dependent type
        typename D = void
        , typename Storage = typename DependOn<Derived, D>::storage_type
     >
     Storage get() const
     {
         // Nothing to change, Derived still complete here
     }
};
```

In fact, for your example `get_set` arguably doesn't need to care about whether a member type is present or not:

```
// std::declval is from <utility>

template<
    typename D = void
    , typename Self = DependOn<Derived, D>
>
auto get() const
-> decltype( std::declval<Self const&>().data )
{ return static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).data; }
```

This implementation of `get` has subtly different semantics from your own in that it returns a reference to `data` but that's on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could figure out is that you're in a chicken/egg problem.

struct A uses  impl_get_set as base, that forces instantiation. But at that point A is incomplete, its contents not yet available. Therefore T::storage_type fails to resolve to anything.

The only workaround I found was to just have another template param for impl_get_set and pass it from above. So go the opposite direction:

```
template<typename T, typename ST>
class impl_get_set {
public:  
    typedef ST storage_type;
    storage_type get() const {
        return static_cast<const T *>(this)->data_;
    }

    void set(storage_type d) {
        *static_cast<T *>(this)->data_ = d;
    }
};

struct A : public impl_get_set<A, int> {
    storage_type data_;
};
```

(A is currently not used in the base, I left it in for possible other plans)